# How to save and get a list of lists using Shared preferences in dart/flutter

Tags: android, list, dart, flutter

I have been trying to save a list of lists using shared preferences in dart. For example, I have a list `List data = [["dave","21","M"],["steven","22","F"]]` and I am trying to save and load as it is but app keeps throwing `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'`

I have tried converting the 2d list into a list using `List new_data = data.expand((i) => i).toList();` and then saving it. But still, the exception persists even though it is a list containing only strings.

Comment: try:
List<String> new_data = data.expand((i) => i).toList();

Comment: @mathronaut Tried that already, it still returns the same exception.

Comment: ok, i'm creating a demo.

Comment: probably easiest to convert it to json and save the resulting string

Comment: @Sukumarvarma try the Richard Heap's solution, that was the solution I was going to suggest you.

Comment: is it not `List<List<String>>` instead?

Comment: Hi. Did you manage to solve the issue? Converting to json and saving the result as a string does not seem to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `jsonEncode` and `jsonDecode()` to get the list out:

```dart
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

List data = [["dave","21","M"],["steven","22","F"]];

handleData() async {
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('key', jsonEncode(data)); // Encode the list here
  print(jsonDecode(prefs.getString('key'))); // Decode then print it out
}
```

Comment: underrated. This answer should be accepted.